# Shortcut to push code to git in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, the only way that I know of to push commits with git is to go into the "..." menu of the Source Control tab and click `Push`.

[image: Exhibit A]

That method seems a bit roundabout to me, especially considering that there is a unique button to commit code right in the tab. Is there a way to have a push button be next to the commit button in VS Code Source Control?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There is a button at the bottom left of the VS Code editor, which you can click to automatically sync your branch with that from remote (i.e. both pull AND push, merging your branch with upstream if necessary). This might or might not be what you want, but it's easy to click this when you know that there are no changes upstream (e.g. when you're working on a project by yourself).

[image]

Otherwise, I frequently bring up the Command Palette with ⇧⌘P (Ctrl-Shift-P on Windows/Linux) and type `gpus`, which brings up `Git: Push` as the first option. (It's been ingrained in my fingers since the days of Sublime Text)

If you are using the later versions of VS Code which has MRU list of command history, you can shorten it even further and just type `gp`, which is exactly what I've been using since [`SublimeGit`](https://github.com/SublimeGit/SublimeGit) in Sublime Text.

[image]

Lastly, another option you may want is to add a custom keyboard shortcut to push changes. You can do this by editing your Keyboard Shortcuts File, and adding something like the following:

```
{
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+p",
        "command": "git.push"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess this works. I would have liked a button in the Source Control tab, but this works too.

Comment: Personally I find that the Command Palette method is the most productive one for me, just fyi!

Comment: @ifconfig and Irvine is there a hotkey to commit and push at same time? Right now if i type in to the git sideview comment, and hit ctrl + enter, it just commits it, it doesnt push it at same time.

Comment: The integrated Keyboard Shortcuts customization tool is great too. Open it with Ctrl+K Ctrl+S

Comment: The sync option used to work for me, but not anymore. Now, when I have commits to push it first tries to pull and then fails due to some uncommitted files.

Answer (score 56):

There is a new setting `Post Commit Command` in vscode 1.30.1 to change the default commit behavior
[image]

Comment: For anyone that can't find it, it's under File>Preferences>Settings>Extensions>Git

Comment: Can also use Ctrl+Comma to bring up settings (guessing that would be Cmd+Comma for Macs).  That seems to be the new normal for settings in Microsoft products (also works in Windows Terminal)

Comment: This is an awesome feature. Hats off to vs code devs.

Answer (score 15):

VSCode has it there but you have to activate it:
1- Go to shortcuts by Command/Ctrl + K + Command/Ctrl + S

2- Then search for "Git Push"

3- Click on the + that appears when you hover over it

4- Finally write the keyboard shortcut you want

- You can also search for Git Pull, Git commit, and even things not related to Git like kill terminal or expand terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own shortcut after doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. I have shown it in the pictures below.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. You can write "git push" to search.
3. Click in front of git push "Settings Icon".
   [image]
4. Click "Edit Icon".
   [image]
5. Then you can write. For example (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>).